# Jetpack compose deep link into nested navigation

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-deep-link, jetpack-compose-navigation

[according to the recommendation of Android developers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav) it is recommended to use nested navigation for the growing project

```
NavHost(navController, startDestination = "home") {
    ...
    loginGraph(navController)
    ...
}
```

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.loginGraph(navController: NavController) {
    navigation(startDestination = "username", route = "login") {
        composable("username") { ... }
        composable("password") { ... }
        composable("registration") { ... }
    }
}
```

but what should i do to be able to deep link into the navigation within navigation like in this example in order to go to the "username" composable

I've already managed to do the normal deep link like what is shown in the [developer page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks)

would it be better to surround the within nested navigation with a composable and put the deep link in there?

```
NavHost(navController, startDestination = "home") {
    ...
    val deeplinkuri = "..."
    composable(
        route="loginGraphScreen",
        deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink {
                    uriPattern = deeplinkuri
                }),
    ){
        loginGraph(navController)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: How did you fixed it? i have the same problem...

Comment: @Eitan check the asnwer that I did, I didn't managed to deep link into nested navigation though

Answer (score 0):

I can't do a nested graph with deep link, so i just make it like an extension of the NavGraphBuilder

it still does the job of making the code more easier to managed while having deep link

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.loginGraph(navController: NavController) {
    composable("username", deepLinks= ....) { ... }
    composable("password") { ... }
    composable("registration") { ... }
}
```